# Python add to existing logging info message

Tags: python, logging

I have a script that starts a process and prints another line when it is done:

```py
import logging
import time


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.info("Starting sleep")
    time.sleep(5)
    logger.info("Finished sleep")

main()
```

This produces the following output:

```
>>> main()
INFO:root:Starting sleep
INFO:root:Finished sleep
```

I want it to only print a single line, like it would in the following case:

```py
import logging
import time


def main():
    print("Starting sleep", end="")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(" Finished sleep")

main()
```

Which results in:

```
>>> main()
Starting sleep Finished sleep
```

Can this be done using the python logging module?